# Sudo update links to amazonaws.com. Why?

Tags: 16.04, amazon

The first lines I get when I do `sudo apt-get update` is:

```
Hit:1 https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/brave-apt xenial InRelease
Get:2 https://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease [3,590 B]
```

Brave is my browser.

What's this amazon link, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: That looks like Brave's repo, if you remove it you won't get updates.

Comment: And "brave browser" was installed through the amazon app store? ;-)

Comment: I guess that's what it should be then.. ALthough I dont' recall installing it through the Amazon app store. I don't even recall ever visiting that app store.

Answer (score 2):

This is only meaning that the repository for the relases of the sofware you use (Brave) is hosted on a server on amazon web services.

You probably manually added that repo when you wanted to install the browser with apt

Removing it will block any futur update